# Messagebox not closing while closing parent for calling Hide or close explicitly

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt5, qmessagebox

I have QMessageBox as member to a widget class 
If the messagebox is kept open and through program if we close widget messagebox is not getting closed. I did setParent also for message box

```
// Code local to a function
reply = m_warningMsg.question(this,"Warning","Do you really want to close the connection",QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No);
if(reply == QMessageBox::No)
{
    return;
}

//Function to close the widget
void Window::closeConnection()
{
    m_warningMsg.setParent(this);
    m_warningMsg.setVisible(true);

    // Code inside if executed but not hiding messagebox
    if(m_warningMsg.isVisible())
    {
        m_warningMsg.close();
        m_warningMsg.hide();
    }
    close();
}
```

Comment: Why do you close your widget if the message box still asks a question that requires user's answer?

Comment: background widget is doing some activity and if user forget to give any input activity will continue and both should close

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`QMessageBox::question()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#question) is a static method so `m_warningMsg` is not the `QMessageBox` that is displayed, as you have passed as a parameter to this as a parent then we can find that `QMessageBox` (note that it is not necessary to use `m_warningMsg`) using [`findchild()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChild):

```
QMessageBox::StandardButton reply = QMessageBox::question(this,"Warning","Do you really want to close the connection",QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No);
if(reply == QMessageBox::No)
{
    return;
}
```

---

```
void Window::closeConnection()
{
    QMessageBox *mbox = findChild<QMessageBox*>();
    if(mbox)
        mbox->close();
    close();
}
```